# Load a .rtf File into a RichTextBox and Maintain/Persist the Formatting

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, richtext

All, I write a log file to a .rtf file which has formatting underlining, bold etc. I have saved this file and want to read it back into the `RichTextBox` at a later time persisting its formatting. I have tried the following

```
tmpRichTextBox.LoadFile(@"F:\Path\File.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

It loads the file but there is none of my original formatting. If I load the .rtf into word, the formatting shows up. How do I read the .rtf back into the `RichTextBox` *including* its formatting?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The code you've supplied should work. Have you tried a different RTF file? I can only imagine that there might be an error in the RTF?

Comment: Yes, it does not format at all...

Answer (score 1):

Did you Check [`NRTFTree`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C).

Its an awesome library for RTF management!

Answer (score 1):

*Edited:*
It's possible that you are losing the formating later in code. There are certain operations that may cause the loss of the formating. For example,
`richTextBox.Font = newFont;`

I had this problem, but luckily I found a way around it. Here's the code that will let you change the font without losing the formating:

```
richTextBox.SelectAll();
richTextBox.SelectionFont = newFont;
string rtf = richTextBox.SelectedRtf;
richTextBox.Font = newFont;
richTextBox.Rtf = rtf;
```

Comment: Hi @Dzienny, it does _not_ 'work', hence the question. If you save an RTF file and then read it back in to a `RichTextBox` the formatting dissapears. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi @Killercam The code that loads an rtf file to a `RichTextBox` does work. It's most likely that you are losing the formating later in the code. I've edited the answer to address this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can save your log file to html format you can read this file with WebBrowser Control.
Like this:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "log1.htm");

      webBrowser1.DocumentText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
   }
```

**This works perfectrly.**